# CoreLocation :: Getting Latitude Longitude Coordinates

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using CoreLocation in my iPhone app and it gives me latitude and longitude like this - 
37.3323°,-122.031°

I want to remove the degree(°) sign at the end. How do I do that ?

The source code I am currently using is -

```
NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, you're explicitly adding it with the `\u00B0`, which is the Unicode number for the degree sign. Just chop that off and just use `@"%g"` and you'll be good.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that you are using the CLLocation's description attribute. If so, don't; use the coordinate attribute instead. It gives you direct access to the numbers, which you can then format as you please.

Comment: I am using the coordinate attribute. I've added the source code in the question

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
```

you are explicitly adding "degree" by appending unicode for degree character. just remove the unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following:

```
double *lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double *lon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
```

//And NSLog

```
NSLog(@"Latitude: %f Longitude: %f", lat, lon);
```